# awk results error with array as variables

Tags: arrays, unix, awk

I have to parse input webserver log files and they hold information about each request took. I have to get the median out of it. I am thinking to hold all these interval in a array, sort it and return the mid element out of it. As a first step I am trying to collect all interval in an array but it looks like awk has problems with array. Please let me know what is wrong with the script, I am getting error like  **illegal reference to variable intvArray** . Can somebody please check what is the problem with intvArray

the script is as following

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf 0.out 1.out 2.out collection.out parsed.out
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX4:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_001.out ./0.out;
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX5:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_002.out ./1.out;
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX3:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_000.out ./2.out;
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX7:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_003.out ./3.out;

cat ./0.out ./1.out 2.out 3.out >> ./collection.out;
grep interval ./collection.out >> ./parsed.out;

sum=0; count=1; intvArray=(0 0);

#awk 'BEGIN {if($12 + 0 == $12){ sum+=$12; count++}} END{  print sum;}' ./parsed.out
#awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; count=0;} {if($12 + 0 == $12){ sum += $12; count++;}} END{print "Count", count, "Average:", sum/count}' ./parsed.out
awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; count=1;intvArray=(0 0);} {if($12 + 0 == $12){ intvArray[count]=$12; count++;}} END{print "Count", count, "Array:", intvArray}' ./parsed.out

#for a in "${intvArray[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done
```

Comment: I think to get a median (average) it is better to add all your items up, and then divide by how many items you have. Your dataset might have a lot of high values and a few low, so the middle-most value will have a high value instead of what you actually want.

Comment: The same goes for when you have a lot of small values and a few high ones, then the middle value will be small. ;)

Comment: I need center element :( had the code for that otherwise, please check  comment awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; count=0;} {if($12 + 0 == $12){ sum += $12; count++;}} END{print "Count", count, "Average:", sum/count}' ./parsed.out

Comment: awk arrays are not shell arrays, your `intvArray=(0 0)` syntax is for a shell array not an awk array.

Comment: awk doesn't do array assignments like bash with `arr=(0 0)` as you have. you need to include keys for your elements, or let the split function make an array from real data for your, i.e. `str="1;2;3"; split(str,arr,";"); for (i in arr) print i"=" arr[i];` Good luck.

Comment: but this will return array of string I guess, I will be in need of array of int

Comment: wrt `getting error like illegal reference to variable intvArray` - why not post the actual error message instead of something "like" the error message so we stand the best chance of figuring out what the error message means and being able to help you? More importantly, if you post some sample input and expected output and tell us what you're trying to do we can help you write a script to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this entirely without temp files:

```
{
    ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX4 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_001.out
    ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX5 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_002.out
    ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX3 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_000.out
    ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX7 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_003.out
} |
awk '
    /interval/ && $12 == $12 + 0 {intvArray[count++] = $12} 
    END {
        print "Count", count, "Array:"
        for (idx=0; idx<count; idx++) print idx, intvArray[idx]
    }
'
```

Now, if you want that awk array in a bash array:

```
intvArray=( $(
    {   ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX4 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_001.out
        ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX5 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_002.out
        ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX3 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_000.out
        ssh root@10.XX.XX.XX7 cat /opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_003.out
    } | awk '/interval/ && $12 == $12 + 0 {print $12}'
) )
```

Answer (score 2):

A few simplifications to your code - without having seen your inputs:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf ?.out collection.out parsed.out

scp root@10.XX.XX.XX4:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_001.out 0.out
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX5:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_002.out 1.out
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX3:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_000.out 2.out
scp root@10.XX.XX.XX7:/opt/tomcat/escr/log/rce_reactive_003.out 3.out

cat {0..3}.out | grep interval > parsed.out

awk 'BEGIN {sum=0; count=0;} {if($12 + 0 == $12){ sum += $12; count++;}} END{print "Count", count, "Average:", sum/count}' parsed.out

awk '{if($12 + 0 == $12)iv[++count]=$12} END{print "Count", count;for(i in iv) print "iv[",i,"] ",iv[i]}' parsed.out
```

Thanks to Ed Morton for the simplifications and improvements he suggests below. I have added them in the main body of my answer here so all can see them easily and nicely formatted:

```
awk '$12 + 0 == $12{sum+=$12;count++} END{print "Count",count,"Average:", sum/count}' parsed.out
```

and also

```
awk '$12 + 0 == $12{iv[++count]=$12} END{print "Count", count;for(i in iv) printf "iv[%d] %d\n",i,iv[i]}' parsed.out
```

Comment: The first awk script can be reduced to `awk '$12 + 0 == $12{sum += $12; count++} END{print "Count", count, "Average:", sum/count}' parsed.out` but you should really do something to handle count==0 in the END section. The second can be `awk '$12 + 0 == $12{iv[++count]=$12} END{print "Count", count;for(i in iv) printf "iv[%d] %d\n",i,iv[i]}' parsed.out`.